# TypeError: function() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

As far as I can see I am only giving my function 6 arguments, not 7 as per the error that is thrown up:

```
mymap.addpoint(float(x[i][7][0]),float(x[i][7][1]), "#0000FF",None,title,str(x[i][0]))
TypeError: addpoint() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)
```

Can someone help? Code below:

```
def plotjobs(x,y): #plots the latitude and longitudes of a job on a map (x would be the job dictionary, y is used to differentiate the filename)
    mymap = pygmapsedit.maps(53.644638, -2.526855, 6)
    for i in x:
        title = "<img style = 'float: left' src='some.gif'><img style = 'float: left' src='someother.gif'><div style = 'float: right; width: 200px'><p><b>Route No.:</b> "+str(x[i][0])+"</p><p><b>Postcode:</b> "+str(x[i][1])+"</p><p><b>Visit Date:</b> "+str(x[i][3])+"</p><p><b>Store Name:</b> "+str(x[i][4])+"</p><p><b>Store Address:</b> "+str(x[i][5])+"</p><p><b>Store Telephone No.:</b> "+str(x[i][6])+"</div>"
        mymap.addpoint(float(x[i][7][0]),float(x[i][7][1]), "#0000FF",None,title,None)
    mymap.draw("./"+str(y)+"'s Route.html")
```

This is the code from the module I'm using (an edited version of pygmaps):

```
def drawpoint(self,f,lat,lon,color,title,windowtext,num):
    f.write('\t\tvar latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f);\n'%(lat,lon))
    f.write('\t\tvar img = "http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/wp-content/uploads/mapicons/shape-default/color-666666/shapecolor-color/shadow-1/border-dark/symbolstyle-white/symbolshadowstyle-dark/gradient-iphone/number_'+num+'.png";\n') #replace with comment above  to go back to default icon
    if windowtext !=None:
        f.write('\t\tvar info = '+'"'+windowtext+'"'+';\n')
    f.write('\t\tvar infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({\n')
    f.write('\t\t});\n')
    f.write('\t\tvar marker = new google.maps.Marker({\n')
    if title !=None:
        f.write('\t\ttitle: "'+str(title)+'",\n')
    f.write('\t\ticon: img,\n')
    f.write('\t\tposition: latlng,\n')
    f.write('\t\tmap: map,\n')
    f.write('\t\tcontent: info\n')
    f.write('\t\t});\n')
    f.write('\t\tmarker.setMap(map);\n')
    f.write('\n')
    f.write('\t\tgoogle.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(content) {\n')
    f.write('\t\t\tinfowindow.setContent(this.content);\n')
    f.write('\t\t\tinfowindow.open(map,this);\n')
    f.write('\t\t});\n')
```

Comment: `self` is an argument that is implicitly given to all bound methods.

Comment: Just glancing at this it looks like you are calling add_point, but you posted the code for the draw_point function. am I missing something?

Comment: @DanHickstein Was going to ask that. What's going on here? And also, which parameter do you need to fill?

Comment: def addpoint(self, lat, lng, color = '#FF0000', title = None, info = None, num = None):
        self.points.append((lat,lng,color[1:],title,info,num))

This is the addpoint function, I think they are related.  It may make more sense if you look at the original pygmaps module: https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/

Comment: @PaulBentham: Are you certain you didn't accidentally define `addpoint()` twice? Your traceback clearly states it is not a method with 7 arguments that you are calling.

Answer (score 2):

`mymap.addpoint` *has* one extra argument, `self`, since it's an instance method. Thus, you're passing 7 arguments there.

Comment: My full code is here: pastebin.com/j2gimp06 My edited pygmaps is here: pastebin.com/zU1JVeWf – Could you help after looking at this... the current error is saying "File "G:\Documents\Digital Boards\pygmapsedit.py", line 83, in drawpoints
    self.drawpoint(f,point[0],point[1],point[2],point[3],point[4],point[5],point[6])
IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Answer (score 1):

Python methods have one extra argument, `self`. The `mymap.addpoint()` method takes `self` plus *five* other arguments.

You are passing in six, plus the bound method first argument `self` makes seven.

Note that the exception occurs for the `mymap.addpoint()` method, **not** for your custom *`maps.drawpoint()`* method (which does take 7 arguments); note the difference in the method names here.

Judging by the unaltered [project documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pygmaps/), you altered `mymap.addpoint()` as well, it normally takes only 4 arguments (not counting `self`).

Comment: I edited addpoint() too and have the same problem.  I think they are related, ie you cant change one without not the other.

Comment: Sure, but without seeing your code there is not that much I can say here; the exception message is rather clear, your code doesn't take 7  arguments, only 6.

Comment: My full code is here:
http://pastebin.com/j2gimp06

My edited pygmaps is here:
http://pastebin.com/zU1JVeWf

the current error is saying "File "G:\Documents\Digital Boards\pygmapsedit.py", line 83, in drawpoints self.drawpoint(f,point[0],point[1],point[2],point[3],point[4],point[5],point[6]) IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Comment: @PaulBentham: You append tuples of length *6* in `addpoint()`, but try to address 7 indices, `0` through to `6`. The highest index you can use is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the error message delude you, when you call an instance method on a python object the first argument will always be `self` which you do not explicitly pass. Therefore, you are actually allowed to pass only 5 arguments but are using 6.